# VirtualBox - Continuous Integration with Secure virtual server

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualbox

I have a repository on the host machine (Windows 7) that I need to expose (via http protocol) to the virtual machine but not the the other world (even other computers on the router).

On the virtual machine (Windows server 2008 R2) I have a deployed web application that I need to be exposed to my host only.

Is that can be achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a new networking interface for your virtual machine.  Configure the interface to [host-only networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly).  With host only networking the adapter only allows traffic between the VM host and the VM guest, without allowing access to the external network.

You can then configure your web server to only serve pages on the host-only network interface.  Your host would need to access the web application using the host-only IP address, obviously.